# jenkins valgrind pattern to find your valgrind xml reports

Tags: xml, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, valgrind

I'm using valgrind plugin for jenkins. During the job build, two valgrind.xml files are generated:

```
./core/valgrind.xml
./wrapper/valgrind.xml
```

In the job configuration, under **Publish Valgrind results**, there is a text box called: Report pattern. I've tried to write the following pattern `*/valgrind.xml` - but only the first report (core) is presented - although the latter is exist in filesystem.

Is it the correct pattern?

I've also tried: `core/valgrind.xml wrapper/valgrind.xml` with no luck.

Comment: Try: `**/valgrind.xml`.

Comment: Thanks I'll try and update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern `*/valgrind.xml` was fine, but the second file `./wrapper/valgrind.xml` was too big (few Megabytes) so it wasn't show.
There was too many memory leaks I guess :-)